# Is there a way to have wildcards in the basePath when reading parquet files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way that I can read multiple partitioned parquet files having different basePath in one go, by using wildcard(*) when using basePath option with spark read? E.g.:

```
spark.read.option("basePath","s3://latest/data/*/").parquet(*dir)
```

Error gotten:

```
error:   pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Option 'basePath' must be a directory"
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I answered your question

Comment: @thebluephantom I have accpeted it. there is no way to do what i am expecting

Comment: People who have downvoted, I would like to say that i have posted this question only after checking it myself.

Comment: the site is hard sometimes, unreasonable at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can have multiple `paths` in combination with a single base path for getting partitioning columns in the DF schema, but you cannot specify multiple `base paths` or use a wildcard as part of that base path.string.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply give the root path,

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://latest/data/")
```

with the options.

```
spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories    true
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive    true
```

Then, the spark will look for the parquet files recursively from the `/data/` folder to the subdirectories.

Below code is the sample.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[2]")
    .setAppName("test")
    .set("spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories","true")
    .set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")

val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://bucket/path/to/base/")
```

---

**SCALA:** I have tested with my multiple CSV files. The tree structure of the directories is

```
.
|-- test=1
|   `-- test1.csv
`-- test=2
    `-- test2.csv
```

where the base path is `s3://bucket/test/`. For each CSV hs the contents

```
test1.csv

x,y,z
tes,45,34
tes,43,67
tes,56,43
raj,45,43
raj,44,67

test2.csv

x,y,z
shd,43,34
adf,2,67
```

and the command

```
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3a://bucket/test/")

df.show(false)
```

gives the result as below:

```
+---+---+---+----+
|x  |y  |z  |test|
+---+---+---+----+
|tes|45 |34 |1   |
|tes|43 |67 |1   |
|tes|56 |43 |1   |
|raj|45 |43 |1   |
|raj|44 |67 |1   |
|shd|43 |34 |2   |
|adf|2  |67 |2   |
+---+---+---+----+
```

---

**PYSPARK**

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .master("yarn") \
  .appName("test") \
  .config("spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories","true") \
  .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true") \
  .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3a://bucket/test/")
df.show(10, False)

+---+---+---+----+
|x  |y  |z  |test|
+---+---+---+----+
|tes|45 |34 |1   |
|tes|43 |67 |1   |
|tes|56 |43 |1   |
|raj|45 |43 |1   |
|raj|44 |67 |1   |
|shd|43 |34 |2   |
|adf|2  |67 |2   |
+---+---+---+----+
```

When I test the pyspark code, I did not break the lines. So, please check it whether it is correct or not. Well, I put the path such as `test=x` and it is recognized as a partition structure, so the results are giving that as a column.

Comment: Can u explain better?

Comment: Yeah. need some explanation on this

Comment: Not convinced answering question at hand

Comment: Does it relate to original question?